# Display Applications that can handle a particular filetype

Tags: android

So, I have the file path of a file in an application & I want to give the user the ability to select from all applications on the phone that can handle/open that file type and then open the file in that applicaton. How do I do this? - performs a similar function to a file manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to pick the type of Intent you want.  This code picks applications that can send the data through SMS/email/etc utilizing `ACTION_SEND`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

Next you need to use putExtra to get the file/message to the Intent.

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(myFile)); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Finally you create a chooser.

```
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "A Custom Message");
startActivity(chooser);
```

Comment: What intent do I pick if I just want the user to view/edit the files?

Comment: Try Intent.ACTION_VIEW or Intent.ACTION_EDIT. There's a list of Intents at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW